# How to optimize N-queen with openmp - C

Tags: c, performance, optimization, openmp, n-queens

I am learning OpenMP and found the following code to solve N-Queens problem. I want to make faster solution with parallel code, but I don't know how to do it. Everytime I tried something, it is only go to worse and slower solution.

This is code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <omp.h>

#define BOARD_SIZE 15

int board[20],solutions;
 
int main() {
  double start_time, end_time, result_time;
  void queen(int row,int n);

  start_time = omp_get_wtime();

  queen(1, BOARD_SIZE);

  end_time = omp_get_wtime();
    result_time = end_time - start_time;
    printf("Time = %.3f seconds\n", result_time);
  printf("Number of solutions: %d\n", solutions);
  return 0;
}
  
/*funtion to check conflicts
If no conflict for desired postion returns 1 otherwise returns 0*/
int place(int row, int column) {
  for(int i=1;i<=row-1;++i) {
    //checking column and diagonal conflicts
    if(board[i]==column)
      return 0;
    else
      if(abs(board[i]-column)==abs(i-row))
      return 0;
  }
  
  return 1; //no conflicts
}
 
//function to check for proper positioning of queen
void queen(int row,int n) {
  for(int column=1;column<=n;++column) {
    if(place(row,column)) {
    board[row]=column; //no conflicts so place queen
    if(row==n) //dead end
      solutions++;
    else //try queen with next position
      queen(row+1,n);
    }
  }
}
```

What can I do for optimize this code?

Comment: What did you tried? If you do not know how to start with, you can give a look to *OpenMP tasks* (especially the OpenMP examples).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To parallelize your code with OpenMP I did the following:

1. I have added `#pragma omp parallel` and `#pragma omp single` before the first call of function `queen`.
2. To avoid data race I added `#pragma omp atomic` before `solutions++;` (Note that I have also tried using reduction, but in that case tasks have to be synchronized, which makes it a slower option).
3. To make parallel recursive calls I had to create a (private) copy of the board (and to pass its pointer to function `queen`). To create tasks I used `#pragma omp task if(row<4)`. Note that `if(row<4)` is used to limit the number of tasks created.

The measured speedup is about 6x on 8 cores.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <omp.h>

#define BOARD_SIZE 15

int solutions;

int main() {
  double start_time, end_time, result_time;
  int board[BOARD_SIZE+1];
  void queen(int row,int n, int*);

  
    start_time = omp_get_wtime();

    #pragma omp parallel
    #pragma omp single
    queen(1, BOARD_SIZE, board);

    end_time = omp_get_wtime();
        result_time = end_time - start_time;
        printf("Time = %.3f seconds\n", result_time);
    printf("Number of solutions: %d\n", solutions);
  
  return 0;
}
  
/*funtion to check conflicts
If no conflict for desired postion returns 1 otherwise returns 0*/
int place(int row, int column, int* board) {
  for(int i=1;i<=row-1;++i) {
    //checking column and diagonal conflicts
    if(board[i]==column)
      return 0;
    else
      if(abs(board[i]-column)==abs(i-row))
      return 0;
  }  
  return 1; //no conflicts
}
 
//function to check for proper positioning of queen
void queen(int row,int n, int* board) {
  for(int column=1;column<=n;++column) {
    if(place(row,column, board)) { 
        if(row==n) //dead end
        {
            #pragma omp atomic
            solutions++;
        }        
        else
        //try queen with next position
        {
            int local_board[BOARD_SIZE+1];
            for(int i=1;i<row;i++) local_board[i]=board[i];  //copy board to local_board
            local_board[row]=column; //no conflicts so place queen            
            #pragma omp task if(row<4)
            queen(row+1,n, local_board);
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Please indicate if you need more explanation.

Comment: You're computing all solutions, right? That will indeed be faster in parallel. I looked at just finding the first solution, and then I'm not getting any speedup.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout Yes, I have used David's code, which computes the number of all possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

1. I see no omp directives in your code.
2. As Jerome suggested, the way to do this is with tasks.
3. I coded this a while ago. Download [my textbook](https://web.corral.tacc.utexas.edu/CompEdu/pdf/pcse/EijkhoutParallelProgramming.pdf) and see the chapter with OMP examples (or [html version](https://theartofhpc.com/pcse/omp-examples.html). The solution uses `taskloop` and `omp cancel taskloop`.
4. Unfortunately, you get no speedup: the sequential code finds the first solution very fast, and going parallel doesn't make it faster.
5. Oh, sorry, this uses C++. I'm sure the translation to C is simple enough. But C++ is a better language these days.